# What differences between MAX3232 and MAX3232E?

Tags: max3232

I'm wondering if just ESD protection or something differs in [MAX3232E](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=MAX3232E&fileType=pdf) vs [MAX3232](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=MAX3232&fileType=pdf). Did I miss something?

I know for C as consumer and I as industrial that differ in operating temperature intervals.

Comment: The "E" is IEC61000-4-2 certified, the other is not (even though it can still meet the requirements)

Comment: @Maple You should make an answer out of this.

Comment: You can find some info [here](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/the-evolution-of-the-rs232-transceivers.html) and an answered question [here](https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface-group/interface/f/interface-forum/357365/max3232-difference-between-packages).
Hope it helps.